# Function is ignored and only trigger at the end of map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having some problems with my function, the problem is all the Establishment.finById() is ignored until the end of the map, I need that findById for every item that enters on if. At the end of the map, finById fires, but only occurs on the last map object. I can work around the problem using another map, but I do not want to do this.
I think the problem is something related to async / wait, but I can not figure out what is.

```
try{
    Logger.log("Info", "Buscando estabelecimentos na API.");
    const url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=' + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&radius=200&type=store&key=' + GOOGLE_PLAY_API;
    axios.get(url).then(response => {
        let resultados = response.data.results;
        if(resultados.length == 0) {
            Logger.log("Info", "Nenhum resultado encontrado pela API");
            return resposta.status(404).send("Nenhum resultado encontrado pela API");
        } else {
            resultados.map((item, i) => {
                let found = item.types.some(r => tipos_estabelecimentos.indexOf(r) >= 0);
                if(found){
                    var _estabelecimento = new Estabelecimento({
                        _id: item.place_id,
                        nome: item.name,
                        localizacao: { type: "Point", coordinates: [item.geometry.location.lng, item.geometry.location.lat]}
                    });
                    Estabelecimento.findById(_estabelecimento._id).then((result) => {
                        if(!result || result.length == 0){
                            _estabelecimento.save().then((success) => {         
                                Logger.log("Info", "Cadastrando novo estabelecimento: " + success);
                                listaEstabelecimentos.push(success);
                            }).catch((error) => {
                                if(error){
                                    Logger.log("Erro", "Erro ao cadastrar estabelecimento " + error);
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Logger.log("Info",  "Estabelecimento " + _estabelecimento.name + " já cadastrado. Pulando...");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        return resposta.status(200).send(listaEstabelecimentos);
    }).catch(error => {
        return resposta.status(500).send(error);
    }); 
} catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in that it's an issue with `findById` being asynchronous. If you store all these asynchronous promises in an array and wait for them to finish with `Promise.all` before you send the `listaEstabelecimentos`, it will work as expected.

```
const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${latitude},${latitude}&radius=200&type=store&key=${GOOGLE_PLAY_API}`;
const listaEstabelecimentos = [];

axios
  .get(url)
  .then(response => {
    let resultados = response.data.results;
    const promises = [];
    if (resultados.length == 0) {
      return resposta.status(404).send("Nenhum resultado encontrado pela API");
    } else {
      resultados.forEach((item, i) => {
        let found = item.types.some(
          r => tipos_estabelecimentos.indexOf(r) >= 0
        );
        if (found) {
          var _estabelecimento = new Estabelecimento({
            _id: item.place_id,
            nome: item.name,
            localizacao: {
              type: "Point",
              coordinates: [
                item.geometry.location.lng,
                item.geometry.location.lat
              ]
            }
          });
          promises.push(
            Estabelecimento.findById(_estabelecimento._id).then(result => {
              if (!result || result.length == 0) {
                _estabelecimento
                  .save()
                  .then(success => {
                    Logger.log(
                      "Info",
                      "Cadastrando novo estabelecimento: " + success
                    );
                    listaEstabelecimentos.push(success);
                  })
                  .catch(error => {
                    if (error) {
                      Logger.log(
                        "Erro",
                        "Erro ao cadastrar estabelecimento " + error
                      );
                    }
                  });
              } else {
                Logger.log(
                  "Info",
                  "Estabelecimento " +
                    _estabelecimento.name +
                    " já cadastrado. Pulando..."
                );
              }
            })
          );
        }
      });
    }
    return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
      return resposta.status(200).send(listaEstabelecimentos);
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    return resposta.status(500).send(error);
  });
```